How do I solve "Attempting to retrieve all CSS keys" when playing DVD
I'm attempting to play a DVD with Kaffeine (VLC gives a similar error).  This has never worked.
[00007b8614002c10] dvdnav demux: DVD Title: ...
[00007b8614002c10] dvdnav demux: DVD Serial Number: ...
[00007b8614002c10] dvdnav demux: DVD Title (Alternative): 
[00007b8614002c10] dvdnav demux: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00fe0000. Regions: 01
[00007b8614002c10] dvdnav demux: Attempting to retrieve all CSS keys
[00007b8614002c10] dvdnav demux: This can take a _long_ time, please be patient

These messages just repeat in the terminal for several minutes before they stop.  I waited an hour after the last message, but nothing happened.
Installed DVD packages:
apt list --installed | grep dvd

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libdvd-pkg/noble,noble,now 1.4.3-1-1 all [installed]
libdvdcss-dev/now 1.4.2-1~local amd64 [installed,local]
libdvdcss2/now 1.4.2-1~local amd64 [installed,local]
libdvdnav4/noble,now 6.1.1-3build1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libdvdread8t64/noble,now 6.1.3-1.1build1 amd64 [installed,automatic]

Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Edit:
I removed and reinstalled ubuntu-restricted-extras.  Here's the output.  Note this gave different output than the original install.
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dotnet-host-8.0 mailcap vim-runtime
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Recommended packages:
  libavcodec-extra
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ubuntu-restricted-extras
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,200 B of archives.
After this operation, 14.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse amd64 ubuntu-restricted-extras amd64 67 [3,200 B]
Fetched 3,200 B in 0s (8,371 B/s)                    
Selecting previously unselected package ubuntu-restricted-extras.
(Reading database ... 224608 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ubuntu-restricted-extras_67_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-restricted-extras (67) ...
Setting up ubuntu-restricted-extras (67) ...
libdvd-pkg: Checking orig.tar integrity...
/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/libdvdcss_1.4.3.orig.tar.bz2: OK
libdvd-pkg: `apt-get check` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting...

Edit  17 October 2024:
$ sudo apt purge libdvd-pkg
[sudo] password for justin: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libdvd-pkg* libdvdcss-dev* libdvdcss2*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 174 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 260388 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libdvdcss-dev:amd64 (1.4.2-1~local) ...
Removing libdvdcss2:amd64 (1.4.2-1~local) ...
Removing libdvd-pkg (1.4.3-1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.39-0ubuntu8.3) ...
(Reading database ... 260339 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for libdvd-pkg (1.4.3-1-1) ...


sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-restricted-extras is already the newest version (67).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

2nd Edit 17 Oct 24:
libdvd-pkg is installed.
$ sudo apt install libdvd-pkg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libdvd-pkg is already the newest version (1.4.3-1-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Attempting to play a DVD repeats these messages for a minute or so, and then it stops.
[00007b8614002c10] dvdnav demux: DVD Title: ...
[00007b8614002c10] dvdnav demux: DVD Serial Number: ...
[00007b8614002c10] dvdnav demux: DVD Title (Alternative): 
[00007b8614002c10] dvdnav demux: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00fe0000. Regions: 01

Edit 18 Oct 24:
apt list --installed | grep -i restricted

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

ubuntu-restricted-addons/noble,now 29 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ubuntu-restricted-extras/noble,now 67 amd64 [installed]


Have you tried sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras ?

You might want to run sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade.  I am pretty certain that the libdvdcss2 should be version 1.4.3-1~local

The restricted extras installed, but there was a message at the end.
All done, no errors. All fonts downloaded and installed. Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.39-0ubuntu8.3) ... Processing triggers for man-db (2.12.0-4build2) ... Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.15.0-1.1ubuntu2) ... libdvd-pkg: Checking orig.tar integrity... /usr/src/libdvd-pkg/libdvdcss_1.4.3.orig.tar.bz2: OK libdvd-pkg: apt-get check failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting...
I did the update and upgrade.  I still show libdvdcss2/now 1.4.2-1~local.

Please edit your question to include the command(s) you used to install "restricted extras" and the full message output.

Full reinstall of ubuntu-restricted-extras added to OP.

Did you upgrade the versions of libdvdcss2 etc? The ones shown in your question are definitely outdated.

I think you have to run sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg to reconfigure or reinstall libdvdcss2

sudo apt purge libdvd-pkg followed by sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras should fix your problem.

Ran purge and install of ubuntu-restricted-extras.  See OP.

Um, you're gonna need libdvd-pkg.

@OrganicMarble My bad, I thought libdvd-pkg was part of ubuntu-restricted-extras as shown in OP install log - "libdvd-pkg: Checking orig.tar integrity..."

Just out of curiosity, what is the output of apt list --installed | grep -i restricted

apt list of restricted posted to OP.

@JustinTaylor So ubuntu-restricted-addons also got installed which is supposed to happen. That's why I asked. Thanks for the information.

I'm at my wit's end with this...  :(
